# box-shadow CSS not being executed in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

The following CSS works in Chrome but not Firefox. It adds `padding` to a wrapped text with `background-color`:

HTML:

```
<span id="titleheader">EVERYONE ACHES TO MAKE A DIFFERENCE</span>
```

CSS:

```
#titleheader {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38);
    line-height: 140% !important;
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
    box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38), -10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;
}
```

But Firefox is not executing this part:

`box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38), -10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;`

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    #titleheader {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38);
        line-height: 140% !important;
        padding-left: 0px;
        padding-right: 0px;
        box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38), -10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;
    }
}
```

My site: http://dev.presencingtheactivefeminine.com/

Comment: I don't see a difference loading your website in Firefox latest or Chrome latest. Can you please add details or a JSFiddle to demonstrate an exact problem? (Where is this code located?

Comment: It's showing up **exactly** like you have it set. It shows a red box on either side of the `#titleHeader`. If you want to see it better, **change its color so that it doesn't exactly match the background**, like `box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.38), -10px 0 0 rgba(255, 255, 0, 0.38) !important;`. Because the color is exactly the same as the background, you are not seeing it.

Comment: No it is not, if you re-size the window so that the title wraps there should be a `left & right padding` on the warped background color, it is there in `all` browsers `but` FF

Comment: @Tim Okay, well you can't leave out details like that. What resolution do I need to resize the browser to in order to see this? Even after resizing, I don't see any difference in your span.

Answer (score 0):

This fixed it in FireFox

You do not need as stated by `@TylerH`

`-moz-box-shadow: 10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38), -10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;`

but you do need to add

`box-decoration-break: clone;`

```
#titleheader {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38);
    box-decoration-break: clone;
    -webkit-box-shadow:  10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38), -10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38) !important; 
    box-shadow:  10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38), -10px 0 0 rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.38) !important;
}
```